# \csname error in defining in loop

Tags: macros, plain-tex

In following snippet I try to use TeX programming to define 
commands `\Ab`, `\Bb`, `\Cb` and so on. Strangely, I get `Missing \endcsname inserted` error. What is my mistake? I hadn't read TeXBook, so it is a bit of magic for me.

```
\input repeat.tex

\repeat\for{charcode}\from{`A}\by{1}\to{`Z}\do{%
  \edef\letter{\char\charcode}
  \expandafter\gdef\csname\letter b\endcsname{{\bf \letter}}
}

\bye
```

Comment: I think I'd have picked a variable name other than '`\charcode`' here: makes life a bit confusing. Your problem is that `\char<number>` does not expand to the letter specified by `<number>`. Could you give more context so we can target what you actually need: there are various 'loop over all the letters' questions on the site already.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\char` is a non expandable instruction to typeset a character, it doesn't construct a character token usable in `\csname`. You want

```
\input repeat.tex

\repeat\for{xcharcode}\from{`A}\by{1}\to{`Z}\do{%
  \begingroup\lccode`\a\xcharcode\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup
  \expandafter\xdef\csname a}b\endcsname{{\noexpand\bf \char\the\xcharcode\space}%
}}

\show\Qb

\bye
```

which makes

```
> \Qb=macro:
->{\bf \char 81 }.
```

Note that it is really unfortunate that `repeat.tex` calls its macro `\repeat` that name is used already in the existing plain (and latex) macro `\loop` so loading that file breaks a lot of existing code. You could just use `\loop` here.

```
{\count0=`A
\loop
 \begingroup\lccode`\a\count0\relax
  \lowercase{\endgroup
  \expandafter\xdef\csname a}b\endcsname{{\noexpand\bf \char\the\count0 \space}}
 \ifnum\count0<`Z
 \advance\count0 1
 \repeat
}
\show\Qb

\bye
```

Answer (score 8):

There are many issues in your code.

1. `\edef\letter{\char\charcode}` doesn't expand anything, because `\charcode` is `\count28` and so, together with `\char`, it's unexpandable; then `\csname\letter b\endcsname` becomes `\csname\char\charcode b\endcsname` which is illegal.
2. Even if that could work, you'd need `\xdef` and not `\gdef`, or any `\Ab` command (assuming the `\csname` problem has been solved) would expand to `{\bf\letter}`.

Actually, it's much simpler:

```
\input repeat.tex
\let\eijkhoutrepeat\repeat
\let\repeat\fi % restore the original meaning    

\eijkhoutrepeat\for{tmpcount}\from{`A}\by{1}\to{`Z}\do{%
  \begingroup\lccode`A\tmpcount
  \lowercase{\endgroup\expandafter\def\csname Ab\endcsname{{\bf A}}}
}
\show\Ab
\show\Zb    
\bye
```

The output is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./rep.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/eijkhout/repeat.tex
Loading loop macro, version 0.93a)
> \Ab=macro:
->{\bf A}.
l.7 \show\Ab

? 
> \Zb=macro:
->{\bf Z}.
l.8 \show\Zb

? 
 )
No pages of output.
```

Answer (score 3):

As they are only 26 letters, a simpler minded method:

```
\def\definethem #1{\ifx #1\stop\else
                     \expandafter\def\csname #1b\endcsname{{\bf #1}}%
                     \expandafter\definethem\fi}

\definethem ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\stop


\csname Ab\endcsname % or \Ab, by why should I make things simple?
\csname Bb\endcsname
\csname Cb\endcsname

\bye
```

[image: ABC]