# Short command for frequently used symbols

Tags: symbols

I am making a TeX file of an old "German" mathematical document, in which the symbols 
`$\mathfrac{A}$`, `$\mathfrak{B}$`, etc. are occurring in every paragraph. So, when I type this, it takes lot of space, especially in equations: like this

```
$\mathfrak{A}\mathfrak{B},\mathfrak{C}]=\langle [AB,C] \, | \, A\in\mathfrak{A}, B\in\mathfrak{B}, C\in\mathfrak{C}\rangle.$
```

How to make a shortcut for the typing of such equations, or symbols?

Comment: `\newcommand{\fA}{\mathfrak{A}}` in the preamble and `\fA` in the text. Don't use `\,|\,`, but `\mid`. Also the period belongs to the text, not to the formula, so the closing should be `$.` and not `.$`

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. Great, its working well. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is also a topic on the site about defining all shortcuts in a single command: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173236/automatically-generate-new-commands