# Macro shortcut for \mathrm command

Tags: macros, amsmath

I am attempting to make a macro shortcut for the `\mathrm` command from `amsmath`.

My idea is that in lieu of writing, for example, `\mathrm{R}` to get the Roman `R` in math mode, I'd like to enter `\RR` instead.  Likewise, suppose I wanted Roman `P`, I'd like instead to enter `\PP`.

The following MWE gets me the Roman `R` symbol, but I'd like this to be maximally flexible for any letter without having to define 52 separate `\aa`, `\bb`, `\cc`  commands.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\RR}{\mathrm{R}}

\begin{document}

$ \RR$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please consider that there might be some commands like `\aa` etc. already. Your request would break this

Comment: many such two letter commands are already defined, notably `\aa` and `\tt`  what's wrong with `\newcommand\R{\mathrm}` then you can use `\R R`, `\R x` etc

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, understood.  It looks like the answers have taken this into consideration, but thanks for the warning.

Comment: I have just modified my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173246/4427 that could be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, I used, to demonstrate, the three-letter sequence, since many two-letter combos are already taken.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgffor}
\foreach\i in{A,...,Z}{\expandafter\gdef\csname\i\i\i\expandafter\endcsname
  \expandafter{\expandafter\mathrm\expandafter{\i}}}
\begin{document}
$\RRR$

$\BBB$
\end{document}
```

For lower-case, an identical loop can be added with only the limits changed to `\foreach\i in{a,...,z}`.

Percusse provided a more arcane version of the definition, which is nonetheless illustrative:

```
\foreach\i in{A,...,Z}{  
  \begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand\gdef\csname\i\i\i\noexpand\endcsname{%
  \noexpand\mathrm{\i}}}\temp
}
```

Nonetheless, David's suggestion of `\newcommand\R{\mathrm}`, which requires a slightly different syntax, is a better approach overall.  I did it this way just to show it could be done.

Comment: I guess `\begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand\gdef\csname\i\i\i\noexpand\endcsname{\noexpand\mathrm{\i}}}\temp` is a bit shorter but it's just TeX mediocrity.

Comment: so many expandafters:-)  sane with fewer: `\foreach\i in{A,...,Z}{\expandafter\gdef\csname\i\i\i\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\expandafter\mathrm\expandafter{\i}}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't know that I could skip those.  Very clever.  I will update.

Comment: by the way, "sane" was a typo for same, not a reflection on your sanity:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Whew!  I almost threw `\zz` back in your face, in umbrage. :^)

Comment: @percusse Got it.  Thanks for the clever technique.  What do the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` accomplish?  I've not seen it used that way, in the middle of a definition.

Comment: Also I've learned it from egreg. It's yet another TeX quirk. It basically makes the temp as if never defined since the definition is performed inside a group.

Comment: Though @DavidCarlisle's solution is a little more elegant (and keeps with the spirit of long-term readability), I'm giving you the check mark since your answer actually matches my desired syntax, regardless of how "unsustainable" my original request was.  Thanks all for the help!

Comment: @grfrazee Thank you so much.  Asking a question is a good way to learn new techniques.

Comment: note @percusse's version is equivalent to `\begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup\gdef\csname\i\i\i\endcsname{\noexpand\mathrm{\i}}}\temp` (`\gdef` isn't expandable so the `\noexpand` isn't doing anything) and relies on the commands such as `\RRR` not being defined. (try doing the loop twice:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Blame egreg he is a bad teacher. Wouldn't the expandafter version have the same problem since csname will expand?

Comment: @percusse no because it only expands once, to `\RRR` but in an edef it expands till it pops.  you want to replace `\noexpand\gdef\csname` by `\gdef\expandafter\noexpand\csname`

Comment: @percusse I taught you the trick, but *you* applied it carelessly. `;-)` Anyway, since this is used in `\foreach`, the trick is not really relevant, because `\temp` would be forgotten anyway.

Comment: @egreg you blame the student I blame the system

Comment: @percusse I added a much less arcane version, with no `\noexpand` and just three `\expandafter`s

Answer (score 9):

Rather than define lots of commands you can define a command with arguments eg

```
\newcommand\R{\mathrm}
```

which allows `\R R`, `\R x`  or `\R{P}` etc.

Although to be honest I would not do that. Any reasonable TeX editor could have (and probably has already) keyboard shortcuts to add `\mathrm` so it's no harder to add and much easier for anyone reading your source to read.  It's worth making aliases for semantic markup so

```
\newcommand\vector{\mathrm}
 ...  \vector{x}...
```

if you are setting vectors in roman, as that allows alternative notations without changing the markup, but just aliasing a font change to use as a font change doesn't really gain a lot.

Comment: I can't seem to find a shortcut for `\mathrm` in TeXstudio, if indeed there is one.  I've gotten tired of typing out `\mathrm` a bunch of times, hah.  Point taken about future readability.

Comment: "[Any reasonable editor](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3766/is-there-a-shortcut-for-mathrm-in-auctex)"  :-)

Comment: Hah.  Us neophytes need more idiot-proof editors :-)

Comment: Any reason not to use `\let\R\mathrm`?

Comment: @PatrickHappel I thought (for once) I'd stick to commands documented in the  latex book not use internal tex primitives:-)

Answer (score 6):

Taking [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393855/macro-shortcut-for-mathrm-command#comment978938_393861) into consideration, maybe all you need is to define a shortcut in texstudio that will automatically insert `\mathrm` for you (replace <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> by your favourite but not yet taken combo).

[image]

Comment: I believe that defining it as you have it (Mac) or `Ctrl + R` (Windows) would rebind the Find/Replace command.  However, it looks like `Alt + Ctrl + R` is unreserved.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @grfrazee `cmd+R` is indeed just a random example, but you got the message :)

Comment: ...and `Alt + Ctrl + R` is reserved too.  Whoops.  `Alt + Shift + R` seems to work though.

Comment: @grfrazee My usual approach to find free combinations is to look through the already defined ones for combinations I never use and change them to something complicated, which will free the combination.

Comment: You mean that you don't use `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + %` on a regular basis? ;)

Comment: @grfrazee Only as yoga exercise for my fingers :)

Answer (score 3):

And here is solution based on TeX primitives and plain TeX macros:

```
\newcount\tmpnum

\def\setRR #1-#2{\tmpnum=`#1
   \loop
      \begingroup\lccode`.=\tmpnum
      \lowercase{\endgroup \expandafter\def\csname..\endcsname{\mathrm{.}}}
      \ifnum\tmpnum<`#2 \advance\tmpnum by1 \repeat
}
\setRR A-Z \setRR a-z

%% test:

\show\RR \show\xx

\bye
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation on the theme:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgffor}

\begingroup
\def\makethiscommand#1{\expandafter\gdef\csname #1#1#1\endcsname{\mathrm{#1}}}
\foreach\i in{A,...,Z}{%
  \expandafter\makethiscommand\expandafter{\i}%
}
\endgroup

\begin{document}
$\RRR$ \texttt{\meaning\RRR}

$\BBB$ \texttt{\meaning\BBB}
\end{document}
```

[image]